# Lightning Connect validation error with Microsoft Azure SQL DB

Tags: lightning-connect, azure

I'm testing Lightning Connect with a Microsoft Azure SQL db.  but I'm getting an error when validating the external data source in Salesforce.  Here's the config:
[image: azure external data source config]

When I click Validate and Sync, I get this error:
The external system is unreachable. Make sure that the URL is correct in the external data source settings, and that the server's SSL certificate is valid for its domain name. Attempted to reach this URL: https://[myazureservername].database.windows.net:1433/$metadata

I have tried Anonymous authentication but I get the same error.  Does anyone know the proper settings to connect to an Azure SQL DB?

I've set up Azure firewall rules for the Salesforce IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that I have to set up an Odata web service in Azure, and this will be the URL used by Lightning Connect.

Comment: "I've set up Azure firewall rules for the Salesforce IP addresses."    
Can I ask how you figured out what the incoming IP addresses are from Salesforce?

Comment: A quick Google search turns up this Salesforce page for their IP ranges: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003652

Comment: Thanks, apparently my Googling skills aren't as good as I thought.